# Why does Intersector.overlaps return false?

Tags: java, libgdx, android-studio

I am trying my hand at creating a simple game using libGDX.

The idea is: We have a hero who jumps and world consist of dynamically created moving platforms in an auto side-scrolling manner. In order to progress our hero need to jump on these platforms and avoid falling. I have figured out how to do this using the built-in libGDX collision detection mechanism.

[image: hero on top of platform]

Code is:

```
    public boolean collides(Hero hero){
    if (position.y < hero.getY() + hero.getHeight()) {
        return Intersector.overlaps(hero.getBoundingRect(),boundingRect);
    }
    return false;
    }
```

But, our hero need to die when hits side of a platform. Following code should do the trick but even though bounding rectangle of hero surely overlaps(see below image) the bounding rectangle of platform `Intersector.overlaps` returns false no matter what.

[image: Hero hits the side of platform]

My code for this task:

```
    public boolean   collidesSide(Hero hero){
    float heroYH = hero.getY() + hero.getHeight();
    float heroXW = hero.getX() + hero.getWidth();
    if (heroYH > position.y && heroXW>position.x){ // Platforms position
        Gdx.app.log("Platform","hero.bound:" + hero.getBoundingRect().toString() + " plat.bound:" +boundingRect.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("Platform","Intersect: " + Intersector.overlaps(hero.getBoundingRect(),boundingRect));
        if (Intersector.overlaps(hero.getBoundingRect(),boundingRect)){
            Gdx.app.log("Platform","CollidesSide: True");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return false;
    }
```

It seems that I have missed some logic or doing something wrong.

How should I handle this issue?

*Also this is the output log*

```
Platform: Intersect: false
Platform: hero.bound:20.0,64.65544,25.0,32.0   plat.bound:-3.0893557,96.0,19.0,5.0
Platform: Intersect: false
Platform: hero.bound:20.0,65.13417,25.0,32.0 plat.bound:-4.4350085,96.0,19.0,5.0
Platform: Intersect: false
Platform: hero.bound:20.0,65.74593,25.0,32.0 plat.bound:-5.779882,96.0,19.0,5.0
Platform: Intersect: false
Platform: hero.bound:20.0,66.43762,25.0,32.0 plat.bound:-7.042242,96.0,19.0,5.0
Platform: Intersect: false
Platform: hero.bound:20.0,67.29663,25.0,32.0 plat.bound:-8.372085,96.0,19.0,5.0
Platform: Intersect: false
```

**UPDATE:**

The Red and Cyan rectangles seen in images are rendered output of Bounding Rectangle(hit boxes) of each object, not actual sprite.

Comment: Every `plat.bound.x` is negative, whereas `hero.bound.x` is 20. So your `boundingRect` which is supposed to be the `plat.bound` is wrong.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I am confused by your comment :/

Comment: How do you get/calculate boundingRect ? it seams wrong. Or its the  boundingRect of another object (not the platform)

Comment: boundingRect is set every time object(platform) updates and setting code is  `boundingRect.set(position.x,position.y, width,height)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few revisions I solved the issue. But not sure why it is resolved.

I was checking for collision in my GameWorld object as shown below:

```
    if (scroller.platformCollides(hero)){
        hero.walk();
        }
    else if (scroller.platformCollidesSide(hero)) {
        if (hero.isAlive()) {
            scroller.stop();
            hero.die();
            hero.decelerate();
            currentState=GameState.GAMEOVER;
        }
```

Then I changed the code to:

```
    if (scroller.platformCollidesSide(hero)) {
        if (hero.isAlive()) {
            scroller.stop();
            hero.die();
            hero.decelerate();
            currentState=GameState.GAMEOVER;
        }
    }
    else if (scroller.platformCollides(hero)){
        hero.walk();
        }
```

which magically solved my issue. But as I said above I don't understand why this worked.

Answer (score 2):

It very much looks like your `boundingRect` is incorrectly calculated.
From your log you've got 5 `boundingRect`s (I've re-ordered them here, right-to-left);

```
-3.0893557, 96.0, 19.0, 5.0
-4.4350085, 96.0, 19.0, 5.0
-5.779882,  96.0, 19.0, 5.0
-7.042242,  96.0, 19.0, 5.0
-8.372085,  96.0, 19.0, 5.0
```

This would mean that all of these 19x5 rectangles are located at Y=96 and then they overlap (for example `3.0893557 + 19.0 = 22.0893557`, which is overlapping all of them). This seems wrong to me because in your screen shot none of the platforms are overlapping with eachother.

Further, your `Hero` is located at `20.0` on the X-axis, but since all platforms are only `19.0` wide, and the right-most one is at `-3.0893557`, none of them will reach the `Hero`. The closest will be `20.0 - (-3.0893557 + 19.0) = 4.0893557` away from the `Hero`.

Double check how the bounding rectangles are calculated (or how the parameters for the bounding rectangles are calculated) and consider debug-rendering them using the `ShapeRenderer` class to visualize them.